# How to prevent HTML5 canvas line width from changing when re-sizing the canvas.

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Assuming that I have an `<canvas>` which contains a line (using `lineTo` function).

The `canvas` changes his dimensions (either both `height` and `width`, `height` or `width`) frequently.

During the `canvas` dimension change, I would like to keep the same **visually** width of the lines.

Thanks a lot.

The following snippet represents the current scenario when the dimensions of the canvas effects the **visually** width of the lines.

```js
var index;
var canvas;
var context;

for (index = 1; index <= 2; index++) {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas" + index);
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(100, 150);
  context.lineTo(450, 50);
  context.lineWidth = 16;
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<h3>
As you can see, both canvas objects has the same line initialization 
in JavaScript code. the only diff between them are the dimensions (in our case, the width).
</h3>
<canvas id="canvas1" style="width:100px"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" style="width:300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a couple things that are going to get weird on you... canvas needs to be sized outside of CSS. By setting size in css you are stretching the canvas vs using it's native sizing.

Notice the difference by switching the sizing on the elements.

The other thing is now that they are sized correctly you're starting the original point outside of the 100px canvas.

Further reading: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-canvas-width

here is a fiddle that shows what is really happening here - https://jsfiddle.net/bopjtwfe/

```js
var index;
var canvas;
var context;

for (index = 1; index <= 2; index++) {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas" + index);
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(10, 10);
  context.lineTo(150, 150);
  context.lineWidth = 16;
  context.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width='100px' height='100px' ></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width='300px' height='300px'></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your straightforward answer, that's exactly what I needed!